# C# Remote Desktop legacy console application

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, cmd

We have an old legacy console application(.exe ingres ABF) that is very slow when run from a user's desktop(as it submits sql to a remote server).

The same application can be run on the same server as the Database and runs very well (currently Windows Server 2016).

But other than giving all the Users Remote Desktop Access to the Server.

Is there anyway they can call this application from there desktops but have it running on the Server ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I wanted to interact and read output from a java console application. What I did was ran it as a C# `Process` and you can configure the input and output of the application.

```
var appInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "your-app.exe",
    Arguments = "arguments with spaces in between",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,  // This is what changes
    RedirectStandardOutput = true, // where the output goes
    WorkingDirectory = "DirectoryOfExe/"
};

var app = new Process();
app.StartInfo = appInfo;

app.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
};


app.Start();
app.BeginOutputReadLine();

var sw = app.StandardInput;

while (true)
{
    sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: @Beckham White.  Brilliant Thanks. How can I press down a key ?

Comment: @NiallO'Dwyer could you please elaborate more on your question?

Comment: So the application is running and I want to press F3 ,F4 or Any keyboard key (in the application)  ?

Comment: @NiallO'Dwyer That is a good question. I have no idea how to do that...